# svm output error in python only sometimes

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

I am applying svm with weighted samples:

The code is:

```
clf=svm.SVC(kernel="rbf",gamma = gamma_current, C = 1)
clf.fit(x_train,y_train,weights)
```

Half the times the `clf.fit` is running fine with output in the console:

```
clf.fit(x_train,y_train,weights)
SVC(C=1, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.5,
kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

whereas at other times:

```
clf.fit(x_train,y_train,weights)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 178, in fit
 fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py", line 233, in _dense_fit
 max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
File "libsvm.pyx", line 220, in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit (sklearn\svm\libsvm.c:2532)
MemoryError
```

How could this be fixed.Thanks

Comment: Well, clearly you've run out of memory. You can monitor memory usage with `top`.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize SVM with sparsify() which uses scipy.sparse matrix can be more memory efficicent than numpy.ndarry.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.sparsify

If you're curious see here for the logic behind the error prompt.